# MPMoviePlayerController play background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, multitasking

I want to play video's sound in the background with MPMoviePlayerController. Past the video is running, but the background sound stops. I want to continue to sound and background (in background only sound). info.plist has Background Mode set to "Audio"

```
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}




- (void)Play_Video{
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];


    self.movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

    self.movieController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    self.movieController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    self.movieController.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.movieController.view.hidden = NO;
    self.movieController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    [self.view addSubview:self.movieController.view];
    self.movieController.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;

    [UrlBlock VideoURL:url success:^(NSURL *URL) {

        if (self.movieController)
            self.movieController.contentURL = URL;
        else
            self.movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:URL];

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(Alert:) withObject:error waitUntilDone:NO];
    }];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be obvious and maybe you just didn't paste it in, but did you override the `- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder` method?

i.e.

```
- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm new to objective-c programming yet. Added to call the block, but still did not work. past the locked screen, the sound stops. I'd appreciate if you help me.

Comment: You can't stop call but you can play the video or sound after call end